# how to order by count

Tags: php, mysql

I have next code :

```
$rez1 = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT producten.id as prodID, producten.*, product_shop_tt.*, product_shop_tt.id AS prshID FROM producten 
                            INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id 
                            WHERE product_shop_tt.shop_id = ". $red["id"] ."");
$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rez1);
$i = 1;

while($red1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez1)){
    $rezOrdDet = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT COUNT(producten.id) as count FROM order_details 
                                     INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
                                     INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
                                     WHERE product_shop_tt_id = ". $red1["prshID"] ." ORDER BY count DESC");
    $br = mysqli_num_rows($rezOrdDet);
    while($rez = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrdDet)){
        echo "Result : " . $rez["count"] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

My problem are results that i get. I want to get results ordered by the count, but i can't get it right. I want results that most appear in order_details table to be displayed above the rest. 
I get next results(numbers are values of count) :

```
Result : 3
Result : 4
Result : 2
Result : 3
```

This is not right order. I want something like

```
Result : 4
Result : 3
Result : 3
Result : 2
```

The problem is that I now get random results and what I would like is that the results are sorted by the value of count. On the first photo is what I get and on the second is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I got the wrong end of the stick there.

Are you trying to order products by the number of orders?

Try a single query. Without seeing your schema it's a bit difficult to follow your current queries, but you could try something like:

```
"SELECT producten.*, product_shop_tt.*, COUNT(order_details.id) AS order_count from producten
  INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
  LEFT JOIN order_details ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
  WHERE product_shop_tt.shop_id = '" . $red['id'] . "'
  GROUP BY producten.id
  ORDER BY order_count DESC"
```

Comment: The same thing. I updated my question with a photo.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I declared the array inside the loop - have amended!

Comment: Ok, now i get the right order, but how to get now my results in that order?

Comment: Just iterate over the counts array with a foreach - added. Or do you mean you want the first result ordered by the count of the second? In which case, you'll definitely be better off doing it in a single query.

Comment: I mean how to order my product by the count? Now i have  `product 1: count = 3
product 2:  count = 4
product 3: count = 2
product 4 :  count = 3` but i want to be : `product 2: count = 4
product 1:  count = 3
product 4: count =3
product 3 :  count = 2` I hope that you understand me :)

Comment: Changed answer to a query

Comment: Great great, works great. Thanks a lot man. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the `count` in `(tilt) sign

```
$newArr = array();
$rez1 = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT producten.id as prodID, producten.*, 
                            product_shop_tt.*, product_shop_tt.id AS prshID FROM producten 
                             INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id 
                            WHERE product_shop_tt.shop_id = ". $red["id"] ."");
$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rez1);
$i = 1;
while($red1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez1))
{
    $rezOrdDet = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT COUNT(producten.id) as `count` FROM order_details 
                                                     INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
                                                     INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
                                                     WHERE product_shop_tt_id = ". $red1["prshID"] ." ORDER BY `count` DESC");
    $br = mysqli_num_rows($rezOrdDet);
    while($rez = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrdDet))
    {
        $newArr[] = $rez["count"];
    }
}

rsort($newArr);
```

Comment: If it solves your answer, then kindly accept it. @Boky

Comment: Nothing new. I get the same results.

Comment: The result is coming depending on the first query. There is nothing to do with count in the socond one.

Comment: yes @b0s3, you are right... I didn't get that at first

Comment: After the edit it is not different than the next (@benJ's) answer.

Comment: yes you are right @b0s3

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single query -

```
"SELECT p.id as prodID, p.*, s.*, 
s.id AS prshID, COUNT(p.id) as res_count 
FROM producten p 
INNER JOIN product_shop_tt s ON p.id = s.product_id 
INNER JOIN order_details o on o.product_shop_tt_id = s.id
WHERE s.shop_id = ". $red["id"] ."
ORDER BY res_count DESC"
```

Comment: In the second one i do not need order_details..

Comment: Then remove the `JOIN` only.

Comment: Now i get only one result in place of 4.

Comment: Check the `join` values or use `LEFT JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use column sequence number in order by clause,

like in you case you can use `order by 1 desc`

Here order by 1 means first column of the result and so on.